# How to get etag of model in controller in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest

I'm trying to implement conditional PUT in Rails 3.1. For this reason, I need to compare the etag passed in through the HTTP request with the model's etag before updating the model.

In the controller, I can access the request etag like this: request.headers['If-Match']

But how can I get to the model's etag? I know Rails generates one because I see it in the HTTP response when I make a request using RESTClient.

I read the Rails source code for fresh?, stale?, and fresh_when but haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks!